# How do I save my object back into my database in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

With [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL) in a ASP.NET MVC website I can display objects (records) from my database table.

Now I would like to create a new object and save it back to the database.

In my Controller, I do this:

```
    var dataContext = new MessageDataContext();
    Message message = new Message();
    message.Action = "save";
    message.Body = "record";
    message.Parameter = "234";
```

And now I want to SAVE it with something like this:

```
message.Save();
```

Or perhaps:

```
dataContext.SubmitChanges(message);
```

But neither of these work.

What is the syntax here to:

- add new objects and save them to the database?
- make changes on existing objects and save them to the database?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
dataContext.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(message);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Assuming you have a `Messages` table mapped into your LINQ to SQL DBML.

Comment: can I have a help with my problem please?

[linked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761598/linq-to-sql-updates-datacontext-but-not-the-database)

Comment: the same action isn't supposet to be accomplish by dataContext.Messages.Attach(message) ???

Comment: @balanza Quite possibly now, but back in 2009 probably not...I use Dapper now instead of LINQ (developed by the Stack team): https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ so I've never kept up with LINQ developments.

Answer (score 9):

To add new objects just do:

```
dbContext.Messages.InsertOnSubmit(message);
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

If you make any changes to previously loaded entities just do:

```
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

If you don't want to submit any changed entity you need to do:

```
dbContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, message);
```