# Data in SQL Server 2008 Express edition does not show up after insert?

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 Express edition database and I am inserting data to it via a windows application, using Linq-to-SQL. I know the data exists in database because when I query the database I get some data but in SQL Server Management Studio when I right click on a table and click even : 'Edit top 200 rows' or 'Select top 1000 rows' I can not view any data ! any helps ?

Comment: Can you please show us your **connection string** that you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach - I would argue this approach is severely flawed. Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `VictoryDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=VictoryDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Answer (score 1):

I believe LinqToSql has a "Save" command that actually writes the data to the database.  Until that happens you are merely holding it in memory.

ETA:  see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428715/how-do-i-save-my-object-back-into-my-database-in-linq-to-sql)