# sql command to simple linq

Tags: sql, linq

```
     UPDATE M_User
     SET id=string1,code=string2,name=string3
     WHERE code=certain_str;
```

can anyone give me the simple LINQ version of this. I tried looking for other post all I see are the ones I cant understand.

Comment: LINQ to what? Entity Framework, NHibernate, Linq-to-SQL? LINQ is a query *only* language, not a replacement for SQL or a complete ORM. Each ORM has its own way of sending changes to the database

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save my object back into my database in LINQ to SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428715/how-do-i-save-my-object-back-into-my-database-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 0):

this might help you.

```
var result =
(from c in db.M_User
where c.Code == certain_Str
select c).First();

// Change the id, code, name
result.id = string1;
result.code = string2;
result.name = string3;

// Ask the DataContext to save all the changes.
db.SubmitChanges();
```